# CSS responsive serrated edge

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gradient

I'm looking to make a **serrated edge** similar to [this](https://localmotors.com/blog/post/zig-zag-borders-in-css/1205/), but I want the triangles on both the left and right side to always start as **whole even triangles**, like this:

[image]

This is slightly difficult if only dealing with **one screen size**, you just have to adjust the gradient size.

But as soon as other screen sizes are introduced, there has to be a **case for each screen size**, which seems like a bad approach.

I'm using Bootstrap 3, and so I can have 3 size cases for `lg, md, sm`, but as soon as it gets down to `xs`, there are a ton of different cases, since on `xs` I want the "paper" object to be the exact width of the screen (with some 15px padding on the sides)

Comment: Outside of Bootstrap, you would do this with an Image Border with `border-image-repeat: round` so you always have whole triangles without any cut-off, though there might be a slight visual deformity applied so they all fit.

Comment: Thank you @Dai this worked well. The only downside is `border-image` is not supported by IE < 11.